# Filter servlet with Spring : HTTP 500 error 

Tags: spring, exception, filter, blazeds

I followed this article : [Spring and servlet filters](http://abhirama.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/spring-and-servlet-filters/) to add a filter on a specific URL.

I added my 'foo' class, which implements 'Filter' interface.

But when I access to my specific URL, an Java exception is catch :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

My technical environment is :

- Spring 2.5
- BlazeDS
- Apache TomCat

Thank you very much for your help,

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

`DelegatingFilterProxy` works by delegating the work of the filter to a bean in the root webapp spring context. If you're getting that error, then you haven't defined one.

You need to make sure something like the following is in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This will obtain the context's bean definitions from `/WEB-INF/application.xml`